# mongoDB and php connectivity ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu 16.04. I want to perform php 7 and mongoDB 2.6 connectivity. I googled a lot, but I couldn't find anything proper. Can anyone give step by step process to perform connectivity setup please. Also I don't know much about the ubuntu system, so please explain those steps also. And pardon me if my English is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I install de driver in php 
php/ext/driver ---you cand download here https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/
and in php/php.ini -->
extension=php_mongodb

and with PHP 7 use something like

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$filter = [];
$options = [
'projection' => ['_id' => 0],
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);
```

Comment: in which php.ini file, should i add extension=php_mongodb  (in apache/php.ini  or cli/php.ini)

Answer (score 2):

I am using php version 7.0 on ubuntu 16.04. I am giving a detailed info for solving the connectivity issue.
First I manually installed mongodb and then the mongodb-php driver for it.

1) Installing mongo db. Enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

In order to properly launch Mongdb as a service, ie automatically starting Mongodb when the system starts, follow the following steps:

Create file mongodb.service in /etc/systemd/system/ by entering the command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

Paste the following contents in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb

$ sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

2) Installing the mongo-php driver:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Also you might receive error: phpize not found. Phpize is a command which is used to create a build environment. This error could appear at the time of installation of any pecl extension. To solve this problem of the phpize command not found, the user has to install the php5-dev package. 
To install it enter the command:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

Then in the php.ini file which is in /etc/php/7.0/apache2 directory, add the mongo db extension:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Add the following line in the file:

extension = mongodb.so;

(Just so you know, the exact location of the file mongodb.so is in /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so.)

So the mongo db is installed along with its driver.

3) Now keep in mind that the mongo-php classes have been changed. Most of the available resources in the net give solutions using old classes which is superseded. Below are the links which you can refer to:

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

http://zetcode.com/db/mongodbphp/

Here are some commands for basic database operations:

```
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(); // Driver Object created
```

To insert data into the database:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$doc = ["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID, "data" => $someData, "info" => $someInfo];

$bulk->insert($doc);

$mng->executeBulkWrite('dbName.collectionName', $bulk);
```

For fetching data:

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]); 

$rows = $mng->executeQuery("dbName.collectionName", $query);

foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
         echo "$row->data - $row->info\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Though i used "extension=mongodb.so" instead of "mongo.so". The folder "/usr/lib/php/20151012/" is the default extension folder, so no need to explicitly specify that.

Comment: I confirm that the library is now named `mongodb.so` and so I has to do